# Помогите решить как правильно поступить

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, ms-access

Здраствуйте, есть небольшая компания, имеющая свою базу данных в MS Access, БД становиться всё больше и соответственно начинает подвисать и имеет много проблем, подкинули работу, перенести эту базу куда-нибудь, что бы была более производительной и добавить больше функционала(например что бы отчёты формировались и отправлялись на почту автоматически в определенное время), прошу совета у опытных, как лучше поступить и куда перенсти всю базу и запрограммировать её, какие нужны будут программы и лицензии? я предпологаю что на MS SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно предполагаете. В Access есть опция перенесения таблиц на MSSQL, а формы, запросы и отчёты останутся в Access. Этим получите следующее:

1. Интерфейс для пользователей не меняется;
2. Таблицы размещены на более  быстром сервере;
3. Для внесения изменений (формы, запросы и отчёты) достаточно
   исправить клиентскую часть и разослать пользователям;
4. MSSQL будет осуществлять полноценный бэкап Ваших данных по
   сделанному расписанию

Насчёт автоматической генерации отчёта: не вижу смысла. Залезть в базу, запустить отчёт и по ПКМ сохранить в pdf/xlsx/cvs очень элементарно...
Хотя в связке Access + Outlook есть ф-ция "сбор данных...". Сам её не использовал, но посмотрите - возможно это то, что Вам надо....
P.s. Сейчас прочёл про данную функцию. Она посылает специально созданную форму для сбора данных у пользователей. Но! Вы можете запрограммировать кнопку на форме на генерацию отчёта и посылку по адресу e-mail.

Comment: Спасибо за то что прояснили некоторые детали

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing. Подскажите пожалуйста по лицензии, если знаете, какую в этом случае надо покупать лицензию?

Comment: @rukia_m Вот здесь по-русски: https://www.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql-server/sql-server-2017-pricing   Описание различий в лицензировании: http://www.softmark.ru/news/articles/detail.php?ID=86455   Конфигуратор лицензий: https://www.msbuy.ru/wizard/product.aspx?p=sql  Рекомендую сначала попробовать MSSQL Server Express: 10Гб на базу Вам хватит, а переехать на более серьёзный вариант - не проблема. Из платных лицензировался бы по схеме "ядро".

Comment: Я читал про них, просто интересно было ваше мнение, в принципе я так и думал, спасибо.

Comment: Не за что. Удачи в разработке